# How to prevent the white flash when I try to go beyond the end/beginning of line?

Tags: error-handling

When I hit the end or beginning of the line and I press to go past it, my echo area flashes white.

This also happens when a function fails.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a bell, you can toggle it with `(setq visible-bell nil)` in your config file. but this does enable the audible which uses your computer's `beep` function

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful. 

I know emacs has amazing documentation. But I am curious how I would have figured that out on my own?

Comment: This is pretty much dumbed down to knowing what things are called, it isn't only important to understand something but it is important to know how to find knowledge too.

Comment: It's not hard to find bell (use the apropos commands. `C-u M-x apropos bell` shows you all you need). But yeah, getting from a flash to a bell isn't that easy. ;-)